# Intuition of homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, intuition

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#:%7E:text=Given%20two%20topological%20spaces%20X,of%20the%20same%20homotopy%20type.), two spaces $X$ and $Y$ are intuitively homotopy equivalent, if they
can be transformed into one another by bending, shrinking and expanding operations. I wondered why this is an accurate intuition of the notion.

Let $I:=[0,1]$. I know that a deformation retraction of a space $X$ onto a subspace $A$ is a family of maps $(f_t)_{t \in I}$, where $f_t:X \to X$ for all $t$ with the properties that $f_0=\mathrm{id}_X$, $f_1(X)=A$ and $f_t|_A=\mathrm{id}_A$, such that the function $F:X \times I \to X, (x,t)\mapsto f_t(x)$ is a map. Intuitively that means that one continuously shrinks the space $X$ to the space $A$, where the points of $A$ are fixed/never moved. To my mind, this represents the shrinking operations, so I would say that, intuitively, that a subspace $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$ if one can continuously shrink $X$ to $A$ without moving the points of $A$.

If this is the case, we have a resulting retraction $r:X \to A$, that is, a map $r:X \to A$ such that $r|_A=\mathrm{id}_A$ and with $r(X)=A$, namely $r:=f_1|_A.$ If $\iota$ denotes the inclusion of $A$ into $X$, we have $r \circ \iota =\mathrm{id}_A$ and $\iota \circ r \simeq \mathrm{id}_X$ since $\iota \circ r=f_1.$ In particular, this is a homotopy equivalence:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be spaces, then they are homotopy equivalent, if there are maps $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f \simeq \mathrm{id}_X$ and $f \circ g \simeq \mathrm{id}_Y$.

Thus, intuitively, the notion of a shrinking process as above gives a homotopy equivalence. However, this doesn't justify the other "implication", that is, why spaces are homotopy equivalent if they are obtained in the way wikipedia claims.

I have read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696041/homotopy-equivalence-intuition) with a similar question and one of the answers mentions that every homotopy equivalence is the composition of deformation retractions. Why is that the case? Perhaps this would help me gain more intuition, but as of now, I don't see why the claim made by wikipedia is correct.

Comment: @Orb Both should be equivalent: You know that $f_1(X) \subseteq A$ by your definition as well as $f_1|_A=\mathrm{id}_A$. Thus $A \subseteq \mathrm{im}(f_1)$ giving equality. Similarly for the retraction case.

Comment: You showed that if $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$ then $X$ and $A$ are homotopy equivalent.
For the other direction see: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33524/904739

Comment: In general if $X$ and $A$ are homotopy equivalent they don't have to be a deformation retract of each other. Take $X = [0,1]^2$ and $A = (\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times [0,1]) \cup (K \times [0,1]) \cup ([0,1]\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace)$ where $K = \lbrace \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace$. Then both $A$ and $X$ are contractible. But there doesn't exist any retraction from $X$ to $A$. So both have to be a deformation retract of a topological space $Z$.

Comment: Wikipedia claims should be taken with a grain of salt... no, I retract that... they should be taken with a block of salt.